# Swift : How $0 works in Array.forEach?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, macos, foreach

I have seen most of the swift developer are starting using .forEach, understood its another way to iterate array. But what is the meaning of '$0' and how it works? If it's an index then it should increment 0,1,2...

```
@IBOutlet var headingLabels: [UILabel]!
....

headingLabels.forEach { $0.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: $0.text!, attributes: [NSKernAttributeName: 1]) }
```

Comment: $0 refer to an object which is kept in the array (UILabel in your example).

Comment: It looks like it's taking the place of the current element in the loop. The number likely indicates the positional argument of the function being used.

Comment: So you mean to say $0 refers to current object?

Comment: it s mean by Shorthand Argument Names $0 - represents first object/current  object

Comment: Note that most Swift developers should not start using `.forEach`. In some specific cases it is useful (particularly at the end of a map/filter chain), but it is not a general-purpose replacement for `for-in`, which is more flexible and generally better Swift. In particular, `for-in` correctly handles `return`, `continue`, and `break`, where `forEach` has somewhat surprising behavior for `return` and does not support the others.

Answer (score 27):

### Short answer

Look at this code

```
let nums = [1,2,3,4]
nums.forEach { print($0) }
```

Here the closure following `forEach`

> I mean this part `{ print($0) }`

is executed 4 times (once for every element inside the array). Each time it is executed `$0` contains a **copy** of the `n-th` element of your the`nums` array.

> So the first time contains `1`, then `2` and so on...

Here's the output

```
1
2
3
4
```

### Comparing `forEach` with the `for-in` construct

So can we say tha `$0` is like the `n` value in the following code?

```
for n in nums {
    print(n)
}
```

Yes, it has pretty much the same meaning.

### How does it work?

The `forEach` method accept a closure. The closure has this signature.

```
(Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Void
```

When you use the `forEach` it makes a "contract" with you.

1. You provide to the `forEach` a closure that accept a single param in input where the param has the same type of the Array
2. The `forEach` will apply that closure to each element of the array.

### Example

```
nums.forEach { (n) in
    print(n)
}
```

However in Swift you can omit explicit names for the parameters of a closure. In this inside the closure you can refer that params using `$0` for the first param, `$1` for the second one and so on.

So the previous snippet of code can be also be written like below

```
nums.forEach {
    print($0)
}
```

Comment: @appzYourFile, how does the contract work under the hood? Do you know where I can find the source of this? Basically I am trying to figure out that when you call a method called foreach on an instance of type array how does that function know about the value present inside the array since all we are passing in that function is an empty closure variable. Right? How doe for each function actually gets the data of the array to iterate over? Thanks!

Comment: @nitinsh99: Take a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html). Specifically the __Inferring Type From Context__ and __Shorthand Argument Names__ paragraphs

Comment: @appzYourLife Great explanation. I've seen this on an online iOS interview test.

Answer (score 7):

> Shorthand Argument Names
>
> Swift automatically provides shorthand argument names to inline
> closures, which can be used to refer to the values of the closure’s
> arguments by the names $0, $1, $2, and so on.
>
> If you use these shorthand argument names within your closure
> expression, you can omit the closure’s argument list from its
> definition, and the number and type of the shorthand argument names
> will be inferred from the expected function type. The in keyword can
> also be omitted, because the closure expression is made up entirely of
> its body:
>
> reversed = names.sort( { $0 > $1 } ) Here, $0 and $1 refer to the
> closure’s first and second String arguments.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Comment: In my case, it's alway $0. But still i can able to iterate all the elements.

Comment: $0 is the first argument in each iteration. Think of a for loop like this: for `(index, element) in list.enumerate() {
    print("Item \(index): \(element)")
}`
$0 would represent element. The only reason you would use this is to write code faster with less lines

Comment: in $0, the 0 (zero) denotes the index of the function/closure argument - not the index of item in the array. This notion is familiar to unix shell-script and C developers where there are arg0 arg1 etc. denoting the arguments of a script or function.

Answer (score 2):

Functions like "forEach", "sort" take closure as an argument. These closures also have arguments, for example to a closure of "forEach" function you can provide your own name of an argument, or use the default one "$0". If the closure has multiple arguments (like function "sort" does) the default ones are gonna be "$0", "$1" if you provide none. Keep in mind closures can expect you to return some value, like "sort" does. You got the logic, here is example:

```
let array: [String] = []
array.forEach { element in
    element.doStuff()
}

array.forEach {
    $0.doStuff()
}

let sortedArray = array.sort { first, second in
    return first < second
}

let sortedArray = array.sort {
    return $0 < $1
}
```