# prepareForReuse is not working properly with imageView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, prepareforreuse

I am trying to add a bottom border to a imageview, whenever my isLive function returns true. I checked the part, and it gets executed only once. However there are multiple cells with a blue bottom border. This code looks like that:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if CommunityViewController().isLive(startTime: startTime, endTime: endTime, name: self.cellChannel[indexPath.row].communityName){
        cell.imageView.addBottomBorderWithColor(color: constants.waterblue, width: 3)
        }
    }
```

And my addBottomBorderWithColor is an extension and looks like this:

```
  func addBottomBorderWithColor(color: UIColor, width: CGFloat) {
    let border = CALayer()
    border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width: self.frame.size.width, height: width)
    self.layer.addSublayer(border)
}
```

As much as I know, I need to delete the bottom border in the prepareForReuse function. I tried to remove it with an other extension:

```
 func removeBottomBorderWithColor(color: UIColor, width: CGFloat) {
    let border = CALayer()
    border.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width: self.frame.size.width, height: width)
    self.layer.addSublayer(border)
    border.removeFromSuperlayer()
}
```

Is the prepareForReuse the right approach or do I need to set it in an other way?

I call the prepareForReuse in the following way :

```
  override func prepareForReuse() {
    self.imageView?.removeBottomBorderWithColor(color: constants.waterblue, width:3)
}
```

Comment: You add a `subLayer`. In prepareForReuse, you add ANOTHER subLayer, and then remove it. But that's not removing the first one.

Comment: @Larme Ok, I updated the function with a global variable. But now I don't even get one bottom border.

Comment: Please update the code in the question to show what you've done now - a "global variable" sounds worrying, the border layer should be a property of the cell

Answer (score 1):

```
self.imageView?.layer.sublayers?.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
```

try putting this code directly in prepare for reuse method. Add the layer in  cellForItemAtIndexPath method.

Comment: $0 will provide each layer once (copy of layer) while iterating through all the sublayers of the imageView. Refer this link for more info : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375417/swift-how-0-works-in-array-foreach