# Need to update only the last record for an NSManagedObject

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I would like to only update the last record within the respective 
attribute. My function below updates all records rather than just the 
last. I've tried other alternatives and am still unable to update only the last record. Any suggestions is greatly appreciated!

```
public func updateLastRecordForEntityManagedObject(_ attributes:    
String...,booleanAttrType: [Bool],stringAttrType: [String,   
erManagedObject: [NSManagedObject] ,
inManagedObjectContext managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext){

erManagedObject.forEach {

//Here, I attempt to Print the last record
if let lastRecord = erManagedObject.last{
    print(" Last Record: \(lastRecord)")

    // Use closures to pass the parameters ($0) and update the last 
    record 

    $0.setValue(booleanAttrType[0], forKeyPath: attributes[0])
    $0.setValue(stringAttrType[0], forKeyPath: attributes[1])

    //Attempt to save the respective records
    do {
    try managedObjectContext.save()
    } catch let error as NSError {
    print("(UPDATE_LAST_RECORD_ERROR) \(error), \
    (error.userInfo)")
    }      
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "last record within respective attribute? That is hard to comprehend, is a "record" the same as an object (in `erManagedObject`) and what does "within" refer to?

Comment: @ Joakim Danielson  - erManagedObject is an Array of NSManagedObjects. So in this case for example, the last managed object array(record) returned is record #52:          })    - 52 : <MyEntity: 0x28089a2b0> (entity: MyEntity; id: 0xcc9a718ff92603b1 <x-coredata://07F3A2D5-43E4-43C8-9D36-9868047D6BCC/MyEntity/p53> ; data: {
    attributeValue1 = 1;
    acceptedTimeStamp = "Mar 26, 2019 at 12:12 PM";
})

Comment: See [Swift : How $0 works in Array.forEach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38375417/swift-how-0-works-in-array-foreach)

Comment: Well you only answered one of my questions but to me the thing is why you do a forEach if you only want to update 1 object and even why you send an array of objects to a function that only updates theist one instead of just sending one.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. Here's the solution:

```
public func updateLastRecordForEntityManagedObject(_ entity: String, _ 
attributes: String...,
booleanAttrType: [Bool], stringAttrType: [String],uuidAttrType:
[UUID],intAttrType:[Int64],
erManagedObject: [NSManagedObject] ,
inManagedObjectContext managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext){

    // Retrieve and Print out the total records
    let recordCount =  erManagedObject.count
    print(" Total Records: \(recordCount)")

        //Obtain the index of the last record and update the record
        if let lastRecord = erManagedObject.last{
            //Print the last record
            print(" Last Record: \(lastRecord)")
            // Obtain the index
            let index = erManagedObject.endIndex - 1
            //Update the last record
            erManagedObject[index].setValue(booleanAttrType[0], forKeyPath: attributes[0])
            erManagedObject[index].setValue(stringAttrType[0], forKeyPath: attributes[1])

            //Attempt to save the record
            do {
                try managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("(UPDATE_LAST_RECORD_ERROR) \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
```